# TypeError: .map is not a function when submit a form

Tags: reactjs, forms, filter

I have a problem I am trying to make a select form where the selection of an option suppose to toggle boolean value in an object from available: true to false. I think my solution is quite promising but I am getting error

```
import { useState } from 'react'


function App() {
  const [time, setTime] = useState("")
  const [availableSlots, setAvailableSlots] = useState([
    {value: '17:00', available: true},
    {value: '18:00', available: true},
    {value: '19:00', available: true},
    {value: '20:00', available: true},
    {value: '21:00', available: true},
    {value: '22:00', available: true}
  ])

  const toggleAv = () => {
    var selectedSlot = availableSlots.find((item) => {
        return item.value === time
    })
    setAvailableSlots(
        ...availableSlots,
        selectedSlot.available = false
    )
    console.log(availableSlots)
  }
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    toggleAv()
  }

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <select 
          name="time" 
          id="time" 
          value={time} 
          onChange={(e) => setTime(e.target.value)}
        >
          {availableSlots.map((item, key) => {
            return <option key={key} value={item.value}>{item.value}</option>
          })}

        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Code works how it should, it just gives error when submitted. Should I use something else instead of find then? I don't see any reason why I couldn't use the .filter method like that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/quirky-volhard-35hm55) repo with the solution. I just created a new array of slots with the updated "available" properties and then passed that new array to the setAvailableSlots() instead of spreading the existing availableSlots array.

here is updated function

```
  const toggleAv = () => {
    const updatedSlots = availableSlots.map((slot) =>
      slot.value === time ? { ...slot, available: false } : slot
    );
    setAvailableSlots(updatedSlots);
    console.log(updatedSlots);
  };
```

Comment: Yep, that actually makes more sense because if I use the suggested for loop, it doesn't update the state, which I was gonna lift up to use globally

Comment: glad that it helped. if my answer is correct then i would be highly obliged if you can mark it as correct

Comment: It works perfect, I was working on finishing my logic so it took me some time, thank you kindly!

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop where it matches the time at index it will update the value. The code you are trying it is a spread operator. It will keep previous values and add one more item which is not a object kind. So it is not taking the .map() function.

const toggleAv = () => {

```
for (var i = 0; i < availableSlots.length; i++) {
  if (availableSlots[i].value === time) {
    availableSlots[i].available = false;
  }
}
```

};

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't realize that the spread operator would add a value

Comment: This solution works too, but I needed to update the state so I could use it globally (I guess I should have mentioned it too), so using the map works better. Thank you